# Where in Umbraco RenderModel comes from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request, umbraco7

I have an app which uses Umbraco7 and there are RenderMVCcontroller's and their index actions take RenderModel as a parameter. I'd like to find the place where the request is intercepted or maybe pre-processed before it gets to my controller. So, a part of request pipeline right before my mvc controller and how to get there.